# Can't upgrade Ubuntu Mate from 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, ubuntu-mate

I managed to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.

Now I can't upgrade from 18.04.

I receive authentication failed.[image]

Any ideas?

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

uname -mrs
Linux 4.15.0-197-generic x86_64

cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu-MATE 16.04.1 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160719)]/ xenial main multiverse restricted universe

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## universe WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu security
## team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ bionic partner
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser/ubuntu xenial main
```

Comment: Your details look *unusual* and don't match (*in my opinion*) what I'd expect to see if you did what you said you did & *release-upgraded* using Ubuntu procedures. You pasted 18.04.1??  A fully-upgraded 18.04 or *bionic* system will report as [18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) if correct procedures are used so I'd check what you actually did.

Comment: It was Ubuntu Mate 16.04 upgrade, if that helps. Really don't know if some things look strange! Ubuntu make all the upgrade & I didn't interfere in any procedure. I managed to upgrade further to 20.04 & I'll give it a try to 22. I hope it won't lock me out again!

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It was simple: I just added the following line at my sources.list

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main restricted
```

Now I'm at 20.04 & have trouble to find my admin account to login!!!!

I realized that the login screen was the problem as it showed me a secondary user where I store my php code and is used as web home folder for Apache to test my code.
I bypassed that problem too with these steps:

```
#find current display manager
sudo cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/sbin/lightdm
#create a configuration file for lightdm that disables auto-login & allows
#manual user selection
#wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM instructions are wrong!
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf
#write there
[Seat:*]
greeter-show-manual-login=true
greeter-hide-users=false
#save & reboot
reboot
```

I can login now with my admin account and also select desktop environment Mate for which I fall in love years ago!

Hope that helps someone.

Have fun!

Comment: thank you shruggy for your idea https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/unable-to-upgrade-from-18-04-to-20-04-a-4175685598/